# python | Get first elements of 2d list

Tags: python, list

i have following List:

```
j = [
    [(1, 100), (2, 80), (3, 40)],
    [(2, 80), (1, 30), (4, 50), (3, 60)],
    [(1, 40), (2, 70), (4, 30)]
]
```

How can i print every first element like this:

```
[1, 2 ,3]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
```

I tried with

```
for i in j:
print(i[0])
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have a `list of lists of tuples`.  You need two loops to cover the `list of lists` part. Also be careful with indentation that is very important in Python.

Comment: What about your current approach isn’t working as you’d like? Think about what additional step (if done on paper) you’d need to take. Then, implement and test this.

Comment: Hello, your code seems ok. Just add a tabulation before `print(i[0])`

Comment: @pyOliv - Have another think about *why* the current approach doesn’t work (fully).

Answer (score 3):

Using `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
[next(zip(*i)) for i in j]
```

---

```
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 4, 3), (1, 2, 4)]
```

Or using a nested loop:

```
[[v[0] for v in i] for i in j]
```

---

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```

Comment: Alternatively `[[k[0] for k in i] for i in j]`

Comment: it's more efficient way, but less readable for ones  who are not common with iterators i belive

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in j:
    print([v[0] for v in i])
```

Answer (score 1):

The ugliest, least pythonic form, but easiest to understand:

```
list_of_tuples = [[(1, 100), (2, 80), (3, 40)],
    [(2, 80), (1, 30), (4, 50), (3, 60)],
    [(1, 40), (2, 70), (4, 30)]]
    

for tuple_ in list_of_tuples : # iterating over the list items, i.e. the tuples
   storage_list=[] # creating an empty list for storage of items we want to print
   for item in tuple_: # iterating over the tuple items
      storage_list.append(item[0]) # storing the first item of each tuple in the created list
   print(storage_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if it had an explanation of the code, and an example of the output so that users don't have to test it to confirm that it works.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin, I absoluotely agree. i changed it accordingly.

Comment: Much better! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's list comprehensions for each list i:

```
for i in j:
    print([x for x,y in i])
```

If you haven't used list comprehensions before, this means for each item in the list i (in this case a tuple (x,y)), use the value of x for this new list we are creating.

Comment: You can just do [x for x,_ in i]